# Sitecore Settings With Page Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I have **Site settings** item for my site, and i have field there for logo, in my code i am using Sitecore Field to display this field on my pages. and from experience editor it can be editable, but when i change the logo and publish the current item from experience editor (ex: home page), all items related to the page is published except the logo. I have to go to **Site settings** item from content editor and publish it. any idea how i can publish it from experience editor (Logo or any fields in **Site Settings**)

Comment: Is the logo editable from the page? If the settings item is referenced correctly, the logo should be editable. Any changes should be saved when the page is saved. This is the same process as if you have a rendering/sublayout that has a datasource. When you edit the content in that rendering, the data for the datasource item is updated when you save.

Comment: @dnstommy Logo is editable yes, and i am reading it directly from the settings item, i know that happens because there is no reference between the current page that i want to publish and the settings item.

Comment: Have you check the box "Publish related items" when you publish the single item? I am guessing it works fine if you publish the whole site?

Comment: Did you publish the changed logo image??

Answer (score 1):

Normally, logo is a field on the home item you don't change it every day.

In your case you can publish your logo using edit related item and publish that item.

Please check below picture: [image]